# Lazy Evaluation and flatMap for Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark job written in Python that works well, but when porting it to Scala, ran into a memory pressure issue. I have a flatMap operation in my code

```
def make_combinations(x:(String, Iterable[String])) = {
      x._2
      .toSeq
      .combinations(2)
      .map({case Seq(a,b) => if (a<b) List(a,b,1) else List(b,a,1)})
      .map(_.mkString(","))
}
```

In Python:

```
def make_combinations(x):
    for a,b in itertools.combinations(x[1], 2):
        yield ','.join(map(str, [a,b,1])) if a < b else ','.join(map(str, [b,a,1]))
```

I can do this exact function in Python using generators and it works with no problem. With Scala, however, I get memory issues since it can generate more data than the machine can hold in memory, but any thoughts why Spark can't spread the data around the nodes like it seems to in Python. Am I messing up laziness here in Scala? Thanks

**EDIT:**
I'm using spark 1.6 on ec2 with spark standalone. The iterable in question can be up to a hundred million in length.

Comment: `x._2.toSeq` There is your memory issue right there: you are changing the iterator into a list in memory all at once.

Comment: I'll try and find a work around without the toSeq to verify, but I expected to have the memory issues from the results of the combinations which (from what I've read) returns an iterator. It's a good point that I'll try to test out though

Comment: The python implementation also seems to realize the iterable as well
(https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: My bad, ignore my comment. Your code seems to run fine on my machine. How big is your `Iterable[String]`? Also what does all of this have to do with Spark? It is all vanilla Scala so far

Comment: `make_combinations(("a", ('a' to 'Z').map(_.toString)))` runs in a fraction of a second

Comment: The iterator is the result of a groupByKey operation, and I'm trying to understand what configuration can help these OOMs and why it doesn't seemingly happen with the Python implementation.